# How to make System.Management.Automation.PowerShell output same as run thru command line

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there any way to get powershell output in c# same way as it is when running command manually via powershell cmd?
I.e. for example:

```
PS C:\temp> gci


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        19.10.2018      9:57            SomeDir
-a---        13.11.2018     17:03       3306 Somelog.log
```

And c# code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("gci");
ICollection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject invoke in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine(invoke.ToString());
}
```

gives me:

```
SomeDir
Somelog.log
```

Comment: The console is taking care of the formatting for you in PowerShell, but you are responsible for it in your own C# code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Append a (final) pipeline segment that calls `Out-String`**, which produces **the same representation that you would see in the console**, as a single, multi-line string:

```
  using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
  {
    ps.AddScript("gci | Out-String");
    foreach (PSObject o in ps.Invoke())
    {
      Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
  }
```

[`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) uses a default output-line width, which you can override with the `-Width` parameter.
To receive the output as a collection of lines instead of as a single, multi-line string, use `-Stream`.

If you want more control over the output formatting, you can precede the `Out-String` call with another pipeline segment that calls one of the `Format-*` cmdlets, such as `Format-Table`.

**Caveat:**

As [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) points out, this approach is **only suitable for obtaining *for-display* output**, because the resulting string is not meant to be used for *programmatic* processing (you've lost the original objects' type information, and the specific output format is not guaranteed to have long-term stability).

Of course, you first can store the original output objects in an intermediate step in order to preserve them for later programmatic processing.

Comment: @boxdog: Thanks - I've added a note to that effect to the answer.